# checkbox at the center of a NScheckboxcell

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, checkbox, nstableview

I am unable to center a checkbox inside a checkbox cell. Tried programmatically and over IB but without luck.

To reproduce add a `NSTableView` and in this add a `NSCheckboxCell`. edit the text of the checkbox to an empty text. Now try to center the box with the alignment button inside the cell. it will stay at the very left.

How can this be done? I would need to do it programmatically so if the answer is for a pro grammatical solution its better. If it is in IB then I am ok anyway and will find the programmatical version myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IB-Version would be to set the 'Position' to be centred.
Change it to be the value in the screenshot.

[image]

I'm currently looking for a non-IB-Solution but the docs don't say anything ...

Comment: You're welcome! Unfortunately I could't find a programmatic solution :( Let me know when you find one ;)

Comment: here we go! ` NSButtonCell * checkBox = [[NSButtonCell alloc] init];
        [checkBox setButtonType:NSSwitchButton];
        [checkBox setImagePosition:NSImageOverlaps];`

Answer (score 0):

The non IB answer is to set the image position.

i.e. swift would be "btnCheck.imagePosition = .ImageOnly"
and ObjC would be [btnCell setImagePosition:NSImageOnly]